# I cannot install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Lenovo G50/70 IntelCore I5 from a Bootable USB

Tags: usb

I created a bootable drive using Universal USB Installer and then UNetbootin, but both times it gave me the same error message telling me that the boot up failed. What should I do?

Comment: Can you please copy the exact message you receive? And also, please tell us if you already did any adjust in BIOS configuration. Maybe you need to do so in order to boot from the USB drive. Also, tell please if you have Windows and what version, you may need to disable secure boot on that.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like:  What the error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 0):

i also have a Lenovo G50-70 and have some strugle but did it.
What i've done:

In BIOS:

- FASTBOOT - DISABLED
- Secure Boot - DISABLED
- BOOT MODE - UEFI
- OPTIMIZED OS - OTHER OS

And make sure you are using a x64 version of ubuntu.